# Where can we find easily documentations about functions/methods provided by libraries?

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everybody,

I'd like to code my own plugins. I did the tutorials from the web site but if I look at the examples, in the .cpp files, many different methods are used to describe the plugin. The problem is that I don't know what these methods do. Moreover, I'd like to use all the functionalities provided by the libraries to be more efficient.

So, my question is :  Where can we find easily documentations about functions/methods provided by libraries ?
Maybe on the Gazebo website ? Or directly in the library folder ?

Thank you in advance

Ronan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17415/where-can-we-find-easily-documentations-about-functions/methods-provided-by-libraries-?/) by [ronan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3910/ronan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here's the API documentation site for Gazebo 7:

http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/7.1.0/index.html

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2